# Angular 2 with ngrx/store, updating property of state object without overwriting the entire object

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm trying to assign a new property of a state object but I can't seem to set it without setting a whole new object, I only want to add a property, not create a whole new object with just that one property.

Here's my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  all: [],
  single: {}
}

export const ModelsReducer: ActionReducer<any> = (state: IModelsStorage = initialState, action: Action) => {

  switch(action.type) {

    case GET_MODELS_SUCCESS: return Object.assign({}, state, {
      all: [...action.payload.data]
    });

    case GET_MODEL_SUCCESS: return Object.assign({}, state, {
      single: action.payload.data
    });

    // How do I only update the single object without overwriting the whole thing?
    case GET_VARIANTS_SUCCESS: return Object.assign({}, state, {
      single: {
        variants: action.payload.data
      }
    });

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With another one Object.assign...

```
case GET_VARIANTS_SUCCESS: return Object.assign({}, state, {
  single: Object.assign(state.single, {
    variants: action.payload.data
  })
});
```

Comment: Figured it out after a while, turned out data from backend was incorrect so this didn't work until that was fixed. Anyway thanks for responding :)